# Key dimensions in Holoviews curve to look up value in dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, holoviews

I want the user of my curve to be able to adjust the curve from the slider (slope), but I want the values from slope to return a different set of values.

So that the Curve will use value 0.5 if user select 1, and 0.8 if user select 5.

I tried with lambda expression (like script below), and some dictionaries (as I think that is the way to go), but I can not get it to work.

```
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')

slope = [1, 5, 10]

def curve(slope):
    x = np.linspace(1,10)
    m = slope.apply(lambda x: 0.5 if slope == 1 else (0.8 if slope == 5 else (1)))
    y = slope*0.5+x
    err = x*m
    return hv.Curve((x, y)) * hv.Spread((x,y,err))


curve_dict = {r:curve(r) for r in slope}

kdims = hv.Dimension(("slope", "slope"))

hv.HoloMap(curve_dict, kdims=kdims)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[np.select()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) changes values based on conditions:

```
slopes = [1, 5, 10]

def curve(slope):
    xs = np.linspace(1,10)
    slope = np.select(
        condlist=[slope==1, slope==5],
        choicelist=[0.5, 0.8],
        default=1,
    )
    ys = slope*0.5+xs
    return hv.Curve((xs, ys))


curve_dict = {slope: curve(slope) for slope in slopes}

hv.HoloMap(curve_dict, kdims='slope')
```